# Subsetting datasets into a list

Tags: r, label, lapply, paste, anova

I am new to R . I've spent hours trying to figure this out and searching Google and SO, but can't seem to find anything that's exactly what I'm looking for. Hopefully you can help?

I have a data set that looks like:

```
Site(factor)    Species           Date               Mass       GDD
1               cockerelli      0017-03-14           2.73       252.1
2               doddsii         0017-01-12           3.73       583.4
4               cockerelli      0017-03-14           2.71       385.4
4               doddsii         0018-05-16           2.22       783.2
1               infrequens      0018-05-16           2.89       583.0
etc.
```

I split() my data frame into a list of data frames that I can then pass into apply() functions.

```
splitdata = split(data, paste(data$Species,data$Site))
```

However, when I use code such as:

```
grmodel = lapply(splitdata, function(x){
  grmodel = aov(x$Mass~x$GDD)
  print(summary(grmodel))
 })
```

I get a huge list of ANOVA summaries (like those below), but I don't know which species and site they belong to.

```
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 x$GDD        1 0.000022 0.0000216   0.044  0.838
 Residuals    9 0.004396 0.0004884               
 1 observation deleted due to missingness
           Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 x$GDD        1 0.0002526 0.0002526    0.65  0.451
 Residuals    6 0.0023319 0.0003887               
 1 observation deleted due to missingness
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to alter the code to tell me which species and site the ANOVA table belong to? I've found some answers that talk about paste() and other functions, but nothing I've tried works.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: If the language is R you should tag it to get more possibilities.

Comment: They should be `names(grmodel)` .

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should probably use `split(data, list(data$Species, data$Site))`. Use something like `dput` to paste a sample of your data here.

Comment: Thanks Alexis! I've changed paste() to list().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the names should be visible, I'm not sure what you're seeing exactly but maybe a reprex would be useful.

You could also try to use `tidy::broom` to see clearer:

```
lapply(split(iris,iris$Species),
       function(x) aov(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width,x))

# $`setosa`
# Call:
#   aov(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = x)
# 
# Terms:
#   Petal.Width Residuals
# Sum of Squares    0.1625262 1.3152738
# Deg. of Freedom           1        48
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.1655341
# Estimated effects may be unbalanced
# 
# $versicolor
# Call:
#   aov(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = x)
# 
# Terms:
#   Petal.Width Residuals
# Sum of Squares     6.695921  4.124079
# Deg. of Freedom           1        48
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.2931183
# Estimated effects may be unbalanced
# 
# $virginica
# Call:
#   aov(formula = Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = x)
# 
# Terms:
#   Petal.Width Residuals
# Sum of Squares     1.548503 13.376297
# Deg. of Freedom           1        48
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.5278947
# Estimated effects may be unbalanced
```

With `tidy::broom` :

```
lapply(split(iris,iris$Species),
       function(x) aov(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width,x) %>% broom::tidy())

# $`setosa`
#          term df     sumsq     meansq statistic    p.value
# 1 Petal.Width  1 0.1625262 0.16252620   5.93128 0.01863892
# 2   Residuals 48 1.3152738 0.02740154        NA         NA
# 
# $versicolor
#          term df    sumsq     meansq statistic      p.value
# 1 Petal.Width  1 6.695921 6.69592109  77.93357 1.271916e-11
# 2   Residuals 48 4.124079 0.08591831        NA           NA
# 
# $virginica
#          term df     sumsq    meansq statistic    p.value
# 1 Petal.Width  1  1.548503 1.5485033  5.556707 0.02253577
# 2   Residuals 48 13.376297 0.2786728        NA         NA
```

Comment: Hi Moody_Mudskipper, thanks for the feedback. I can't seem to get this to work though... Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The names of the result of `split` are the values of the second argument coerced to `character`-class and `lapply` preserves these names, so you should not need to add back any names, but rather just look at:

```
 names(grmodel)
```

Perhaps you want to do this for output:

```
 for( i in names(grmodel) ){ cat(i);
                              cat( : : :\n");
                               print(grmodel[[i]]);
                                cat("\n\n")}
```

.... which just prints the names and a bit of spacing for each item in the grmodels list.

Comment: 42-, that's super helpful! Is there any way to paste these back in above each model within the lapply() function?

Comment: The names are already there. If you have a desire for text output then look at `cat` and `print`. The `cat` function cannot handle lists but usually there is a print method for items that have a class.